# Query Entries by Tag

Tags: templating, entries, tags

I want to only show entries that match a specific tag. I'm trying to do something like:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('blog').relatedTo('tagName').order('score') as entriesOnPage %}
```

This doesn't seem to net any results though. Is `.relatedTo()` not the way to go when limiting results to a specific tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need to get the tag model first.

```twig
{% set tag = craft.tags.search('My Tag').first() %}
{% if tag %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag) %}
{% endif %}
```

Replace `search` with whatever other information you have from the tag, to get more precise results, e.g., `slug`, `id` properties.