# Get entries where tag = value

Tags: query, tag

Let's say I have a tag group with handle **genre**.

I can make an entry contain information about this tag by creating a field of type tag that uses this group.

So I would have a field with handle **genreTag** added to the entry with handle **movies**.

*(Note: I don't see the point of having to create an intermediary field, instead of just adding the tag selector to the entry. Why would I have multiple fields for the same tag group?)*

Now I need to query entries that have a genre of adventure, for example.

I read [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/32950/display-entries-by-tag), [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14083/query-entries-by-tag), [the docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/tags.html), and still don't get it:

As far as I understand, it would be done as follows:

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.genre('adventure').one() %}
{% if tag %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag) %}
{% endif %}
{% dd entries %}
```

[image]

And doing it by the field handle instead of the tag handle:

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.genreTag('adventure').one() %}
{% if tag %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag) %}
{% endif %}
{% dd entries %}
```

[image]

How should I approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the actual tag before passing it into `relatedTo()`. The data you have to work with in your example ("adventure") is a tag *slug*, so query for that using `.slug()`:

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.group('genre').slug('adventure').one() %}
{% if tag %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag).all() %}
{% endif %}
{% dd entries %}
```

(...and don't forget to also execute your entries query with `.all()`).

I'm afraid I don't quite understand your other question about creating an "intermediary field"...? All you need to do is 1) create a tag group and 2) create a field that allows entries to select tags, optionally filtered by that group if you have multiple groups.